# Изменение свойств элемента из другого потока

Tags: c#, wpf

При выполнении этого кода

```
Paragraph par =new Paragraph();
par.Inlines.Add(msgToSend.strMessage);
ChatBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par);
```

Возникает исключение "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.".Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: посмотрите на [это](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=145681). Ключевое слово - `invoke`.

Comment: я пробовал вместо ChatBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par); писать this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { ChatBox.Document.Blocks.Add(par); })); результат тот же. Можно пример кода именно в моем случае?

Comment: А какое исключение возникает при попытке использовать Dispatcher? Такое же?

Comment: Да, такое же.

Comment: Используется делегат AsyncCallback который и создает новый поток, если это поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно не самый лучший способ, но в моем случае работает. Использовал form.invoke. Делал прогресс бар, который обновлялся в окне, в зависимости от вычислений в другом потоке.
Итак, код в главном окне типа ImageConverterForm : Form с прогресс баром

```
public void ProgressHandler(int p)
    {
        if (progressBar.Value < progressBar.Maximum)
        {
            progressBar.Value += p;
        }
    }
```

Код вызова изменения значения свойства

```
MainForm.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
    MainForm.ProgressHandler(1);
}));
```

**Update:**
для WPF приложения ничего не изменилось кроме вызова Invoke. Новая форма

```
MainForm.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        MainForm.ProgressHandler(1);
    }));
```

где MainForm это форма InvokeMainWindow : Window

Comment: Я использую WPF а не Windows Forms.

Comment: повторил тоже самое для WPF, ничего не изменилось, кроме строки
MainForm.Invoke(
стало 
main.Dispatcher.Invoke(

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)

Comment: Может быть, в вашем случае лучше `BeginInvoke`. И `new ThreadStart` -- лишнее.

Comment: На счет BeginInvoke может быть, а на счет new ThreadStart поясните. Invoke на вход принимает делегат, а без new ThreadStart это анонимный метод, а не делегат. Студия не скомпилила без ThreadStart.

Comment: @Carma: я не вполне правильно выразился, сорри. У `ThreadStart` есть определённая семантика -- это делегат, используемый для запуска нового потока. Я обычно пишу так:

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MainForm.ProgressHandler(1)));

то есть пользуюсь более нейтральным `Action`.